# how to add numbers coming from an output created by a file

Tags: python

I get this

```
Enter file name: filename.txt
0.8475
0.6178
0.6961
0.7565
0.7626
```

as an output by reading a file from my pc. I want to add these together and then divide them by 5. I need the average number of those five numbers. I can't do it by hand because in reality the numbers are much more than 5.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Show us your attempt and what you're getting stuck on

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting all of the values in a list. If its a string of numbers divided by a space, you can use bluit-in Split() function, and convert them to a list of floats:

```
numbersInTextFile = "0.8475 0.6178 0.6961 0.7565 0.7626"
floatsList = [float(x) for x in numbersInTextFile.split()]
```

Then you can use a simple division to get the average:

```
average = sum(floatsList) / len(floatsList)
print("The average float is" + str(round(average, 2)))
```

Comment: 1. Split is not a build-in, it's a method. 2. Split by default splits on any whitespace, not only single space. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, highly appreciated. I guess he has to ensure there aren't any unneeded white spaces, just the ones between the floats.

Comment: Please use gender-neutral pronoun "they" unless you know person's pronouns. Not everybody on the internet is a guy. :) https://stackoverflow.com/conduct "Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate. "  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns - here's more about what it means